# React-native - animate a component on click

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native and I'm trying to make a lil animation, after reading the Animation doc I understood that I've to use `createAnimatedComponent` component for handling with animation, so this is my component that I want to run the animation on.

```
const AnimateCmp = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(styled.View` 
  position: absolute;
  left: ${({ left }) => left ? 0 : '50%'};
  width: 50%;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-top-color: red;
`);
```

I'm using styled component (but nothing that should interrupt the animation), now the problem is that I'm not sure how to continue from here as you guys can see `left` will return true when i need it fully left and false when i need it fully right. any directions how to make it done.

```
<AnimateCmp left={true} />
```

just make it clear I'm aiming for the same result as if I would do it like that in css
`transition: left 0.5s linear;`

thanks!

Comment: Try looking at the documentation for the Animated library on the react-native documentation, instead of the Animation docs. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html

Comment: Hey @William thanks for the reply, the idea is that I'm not sure how to work with these I really don't get much for the doc there. can u guide me a bit more please ?

I don't see any example how they 'play' with the `left` of on absolute component.

Comment: I can throw an example in here if I remember tomorrow during work. The animated library is definitely what you’re looking for here though, if you need the answer in a hurry there are loads of articles that go through how it’s used.